# Is there a way to "install" nuget package like the way Visual Studio does, but on a deployment server

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, continuous-deployment

**Background:**

I am reasonably new to packaging and publishing nuget. Long story short, I have a C# project (Let's call it MYAPI project) which depends on a bunch of other nuget packages. Some consumers of MYAPI, expect to reference it as a nuget package and deal with their products' deployment on their own, while some other consumers expect MYAPI dlls to be installed in specific folders from where they will pick it up at runtime.

So I have packaged MYAPI as a nuget and published it onto an internal nuget server.

**Issue:**

How do I install my nuget package onto the servers in a way that it will have all the required dependencies. I want it to look like how the `bin\debug` folder looks like i.e. based on the target framework, copy the relevant files from all the dependency nuget packages including the main nuget package (MYAPI in this case)

I know I can achieve this by packaging MYAPI as a zip file or an msi in addition to the nuget package. But I don't want multiple types of packages for MYAPI, and would prefer to stick to just nuget package. I also understand I can reference all the dependency in my `<files>` section of nuspec, but I think it is a poor man's way of doing it.

Is there a way to do it just like Visual Studio does it i.e. download main nuget package and all its dependencies, extract them and then copy the relevant (framework version based) files from all the extracted nuget packages into the `bin\debug` folder. If that is not available out of the box, can someone point me to the "intelligence" VS uses to copy the files into bin\debug folder, so i can replicate it in an install script.

**EDIT:**

This is a regular .NET Framework project, and I am talking of installing on say a production server where development tools like MSBuild, VS won't be available. I can still have the nuget.exe command as it is a single executable.

Comment: do a nuget restore. theres no need to install. what kind of c# project is it? .net core or framework?

Comment: you should build a published copy of your output.

Comment: that’s the right way to do it. There’s plenty of hosted ci services

Comment: Nuget should handle dependencies for you

Comment: @DanielA.White The situation is that the nupkg file from the repo, has all the information it needs, but there is no command that I can run on a prod server to get all files, including dependencies, that are required by my dll to be useful for another product that wants to load my dll using say `Assembly.LoadFrom` at runtime. I have got it covered for consumers who link with me at build time as their VS has the intelligence to do that

Comment: You are walking on the wrong path. W?hat do you want to do, write your own nuget package manager? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools ??.. Sounds like you will do much better using Inno setup or similar. You can publish your app for multiple targets

Comment: If you really want it to be as simple as possible, use tools like IL-Repack to merge all assemblies into a single one and internalize necessary classes, and then ship a single NuGet package with all the dependencies bundled. There are other options, but what to choose really depends on your exact requirements, which you don't describe clear enough.

Comment: @LexLi my nuget package needs to cater to 2 set of software users 1st set uses it by adding a nuget reference in visual studio during development time (so they are responsible to deploy it with their software). nuget packaging works great for this. 2nd group dynamically loads my assemblies at runtime using Assembly.LoadFrom (so they expect me to deploy my assemblies separately from their product). Traditionally this was done using msi or zip archives, but i want to avoid a nuget and a zip for the same logical group of assemblies. So how can i use the nuget to provide that facility

Comment: NuGet packages are simply ZIP packages. So they can even unzip in code and then call `Assembly.LoadFrom`. I see no reason to further complicate the things.

Comment: @LexLi except they will not contain all the dependency dlls in a single folder like a deployment zip archive

Comment: How many dependencies are in scope? Like I commented above, merging all dependencies is a feasible approach, especially when you want to avoid conflicts with the dependencies of your users' projects.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to “install” nuget package like the way Visual Studio
>   does, but on a deployment server

I think you have some misunderstanding about this issue and I am afraid what you want can not be implemented by **nuget**.

**Actually, it is MSBuild job to copy related nuget package's content into bin\Debug.**

**In fact**, **MSBuild**(`MSBuild.exe`) is an executable with a vs development environment.

**Nuget** is just responsible for downloading the package to your local and then associating it with your project. The actual content copy operation is purely a job of **MSBuild**.

In **VS IDE**, **MSBuild** is responsible for this operation. When you click build (actually it calls **MSBuild.exe**), the dependency DLLs of nuget package will be copied to your output folder.

**To prove it**, you can create a new empty project and then install this nuget package, then check whether the files are under bin\Debug. After that, please execute **Build** to check whether the files exists.

**Solution**

Since **VS2017**, **MSBuild** can be installed separately without **VS IDE**.

You can install [Build Tool for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).

Under **All Downloads**--> **Tools for Visual Studio 2019**--> **Build Tool for Visual Studio 2019**

[image]

**Since** it can be installed separately from VS and is lightweight, many developers now use this to build projects on production servers.

When you use `nuget.exe` install such nuget package in your project,then use Build tool to execute such command `msbuild xxx\xxx\xxx.csproj -t:build` to build project. After that, you will see them in `bin\Debug` folder.

**Update 1**

**Actually**, nuget does the job which decides which corresponding dependencies to copy. But nuget passes these info into **MSBuild**. Nuget just determines the corresponding information which is like making a plan ,the specific action is performed by **MSBuild**, including reference, restore, copy, and so on. So you should run **MSBuild** to get what you want so far.

**In addition**, if you still get what you want and skip **MSBuild** to get the file directly, you could [suggest a feature to the Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).(click **Suggest a Feature**).

Comment: I understand that MSBuild actually copies the dll from the correct `packages\lib\**\net*` folder based on copy local flag, but nuget decides what dependencies to download, what `lib\net*` folder to use, and such pieces of logic which provide the intelligence. The actual copy part can be easily replicated with a copy command if the intelligent part can be accomplished by some nuget command or similar tool

Comment: I think you have some misunderstanding. Actually, nuget does the job which decides which corresponding dependencies to copy. But nuget passes these info into MSBuild. Nuget just determines the corresponding information which is like making a plan ,the specific action is performed by MSBuild, including `reference`, `restore`, `copy`, and so on. So you should run MSBuild to get what you want so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary/publish project. Create the project with whatever TFM you want, add a PackageReference to the package, run `dotnet publish`, then delete `<project_name>.*` from the publish directory.